# MySQL Select customers with no orders in 3 months

Tags: mysql, date, max

I have a table (order) where all data is stored for an order.

I would like to list all customers that have place an order/orders from us, but limit them to customers that have not placed an order since, let's say 3 months.

Here are the relevant table info from the db (order):

order_id,
customer_id,
firstname,
lastname,
date_added

Thanks in advance for you assistance!

Comment: What format is date_added? Datetime, time, int, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want the customer_id, first and last names and date_added is some valid time field like timestamp, date, or datetime (not a string).

```
SELECT o.customer_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, MAX(o.date_added) AS latest_date FROM `order` o 
  LEFT JOIN `order` o2 ON o.customer_id = o2.customer_id 
                    AND o2.date_added >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
 WHERE o2.order_id IS NULL
 GROUP BY o.customer_id, o.firstname, o.lastname
```

Note the backticks on the table name 'order'.  This is because `ORDER` is a reserved word in Mysql.  Try to avoid using reserved words for naming DBs, tables, or columns--it always bite you in the butt.

Think about it as this, give me all users, include if present all their order info for the orders are within 3 months, then only show me those that have no order.

If you provide a schema for your customer table, I could make this a lot cleaner and avoid the `group by`.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me a SQL Error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o LEFT JOIN order o2 ON o.customer_id = o2.customer_id ' at line 1

I would like to see what customers have NOT made an order in the last 3 months.

Comment: I think it may be choking on the date math and doesn't like it inline like you have.  I would change to >= DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH ) -- by adding negative 3 months vs a direct subtraction which might be the cause of failure.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work on your test site. Can it be that my date_added is datetime and not timestamp?

Comment: @HansLernestål oh crap... order is a reserved word, overlooked that.   quote it with backticks--see my example.  Avoid naming columns and tables mysql reserved words in the future https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @HansLernestål See my edit.  It will return the last order date from those who's latest order was more than 3 months ago.